# Find a prime $p>5$ such that $x^2 +1$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

> Find a prime $p>5$ such that $x^2 +1$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$.

Can anyone please give me some hints as to how I can go about finding this value of $p$?

Comment: Hint:  all you need is a prime $p$ which divides some $n^2+1$.  Just try various $n$.

Comment: Since $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is degree $2$ it is reducible if and only if it has a root. So you want to choose $p$ so that $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. There is actually a theorem totally classifying which $p$ this is true for.

Comment: @lulu . If $n=5, n^2 + 1 = 26 = 2(13)$, so I must choose $p=13$?

Comment: @user290425  That'll do!  or use $4^2+1=17$ and choose $p=17$.

Comment: @user290425  There's a general theorem that says that any $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ will work, but if all you want are a few examples they aren't hard to generate.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Quadratic_residues.

Answer (score 1):

The comments take care of it fully. But you need an “$i$” in your field $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. In other words, you need the group $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^*$ — the nonzero residues modulo $p$ — to have order divisible by $4$. In a word, $p\equiv1\pmod4$. Since the group $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^*$ is cyclic, when it’s of order divisible by $4$ then it’ll have an element of period $4$, i.e. an “$i$”. For $p=13$, you can take your $i$ to be $5$, for $p=17$, you can take your $i$ to be $4$, etc.